# Three-mesh-bvh stop drag after collision

Tags: three.js, collision-detection

I’m using [three-mesh-bvh](https://github.com/gkjohnson/three-mesh-bvh) to check collision between 2 object in Threejs.
The function `intersectsGeometry` working for collision.
I edited the `TransformControl.js` to check collision when dragging, like:

```
checkCollision(item1, item2) {
        if (item1.isMesh && item2.isMesh) {
            item1?.geometry?.computeBoundsTree()
            item2?.geometry?.computeBoundsTree()
            const transformMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4().copy( item1.matrixWorld ).invert().multiply( item2.matrixWorld );
            const hit = item1.geometry.boundsTree.intersectsGeometry( item2.geometry, transformMatrix )
            return hit;
        }
        return false
    }
```

And, in the `pointerMove` function, with translate mode, I added below function to prevent drag after collision, like:

```
checkOverlap() {
    const spheres = editor.scene.children.filter((item) => item.uuid !== object.uuid) // get object is not selecting
        // let's say, i just get the first object to test
    const hit = this.checkCollision(object, spheres[0]);
    if (!hit) {
          object.position.copy(this._offset).add(this._positionStart)
    }
}
```

Of course, it stop after collision. But I can drag it again after collision, because it checked collision first.
I look forward to any helpful
Thank you~